# Photometry in SExtractor vs Python

Tags: python, photometry, magnitude, astropy

I wanted to find stars in the dwarf Spheroidal (dSph) galaxy. I performed photometry using SExtractor and in Python using DaoStarFinder and other astropy packages. However, while extracting the magnitudes, the Python-based magnitudes were a lot different from the SExtractor-based magnitudes (using MAG_BEST command). Here is my python code.

```
from astropy import wcs
from astropy import units as u
hdulist = fits.open('ccd0.fits')
data = hdulist[0].data

# Load the WCS information from the FITS header
image_wcs = WCS(hdulist[0].header)


pixelscale = np.mean(wcs.utils.proj_plane_pixel_scales(image_wcs) * u.degree).to('arcsec')

# Find the sources using DaoFinder

from photutils import DAOStarFinder
fwhm=1.5 / float(pixelscale/u.arcsec)
sigma_detection = 5.0
daofind = DAOStarFinder(fwhm=fwhm, threshold=sigma_detection*std)    
sources = daofind(hdulist[0].data - median)    
#print(sources)


# adding ra and dec to the columns list of the sources table
from astropy.wcs import WCS

x = np.array(sources['xcentroid'])
y = np.array(sources['ycentroid'])

# Convert the x and y pixel positions to RA and Dec coordinates
sky = image_wcs.pixel_to_world(x, y)
ra, dec = sky.ra.to(u.deg), sky.dec.to(u.deg)

# Add the RA and Dec columns to the table
sources['RA'] = ra
sources['Dec'] = dec


''' remove the outer found detections (xsize and ysize are added because there are black bad pixels around the edges, 
13 added instead of 12.5=radius to avoid the detected sources circular apertures)'''

xsize = 63+13
ysize = 69+13
hxsize = (xsize - 1) / 2
hysize = (ysize - 1) / 2
x = sources['xcentroid'] 
y = sources['ycentroid'] 
mask = ((x > hxsize) & (x < (data.shape[1] -1 - hxsize)) &
        (y > hysize) & (y < (data.shape[0] -1 - hysize))) 

from astropy.table import Table
sources_new = Table()
sources_new['x'] = x[mask]  
sources_new['y'] = y[mask] 

# masked/final detected sources
x = sources_new['x'] 
y = sources_new['y'] 

# Define the radius of the circles
radius = 12.5

# Create the circular apertures around the detected stars (after removing outliers)
positions = np.transpose([x, y])
apertures = CircularAperture(positions, r=radius)

# Plot the image with the circular apertures
plt.style.use(astropy_mpl_style)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
norm = simple_norm(data, 'power',power=7.0, percent=99.0)
plt.imshow(data, norm=norm, origin='lower', cmap='inferno')
apertures.plot(color='white', lw=1, alpha=1)
plt.grid('off')
plt.show()

#add the masked sources to a new table

from astropy.table import Table
params_table = Table(names=('ra', 'dec', 'mag'), dtype=('float','float','float'))

#Loop over the mask values and add the i-th value and its index to the table
for i, value in enumerate(mask):
    if value:
        params_table.add_row((sources['RA'][i], sources['Dec'][i], sources['mag'][i]))
```

The magnitudes here range from 0 to -8, whereas the SExtractor-based magnitude ranges from -8 to-17. Why is there a such discrepancy?

Comment: What is the `MAG_ZEROPOINT` set to for SExtractor ? SExtractor calcs mags as $MAG\_ZEROPOINT-2.5*\log10(flux)$; `DaoStarFinder` assumes `MAG_ZEROPOINT=0`

Comment: @astrosnapper Currently in SExtractor, it is set to 0. I need to set it up to the zero point of the CFHT MegaCam 'g' and 'i' filter values.